# React Native Tab Navigator specific number of Navigation Screens at the Bottom

Tags: react-native

So I have this bottom tab navigator but I need more screens in the background. To be able to navigate to those background screens I need to declare them in the tab navigator, however they get added automatically at the bottom. How do I fix this, so only the 5 wanted screens show?

Screens that should not be shown are 'DailySummaryFood' and 'AfterScan'

My MainContainer

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { NavigationContainer, DefaultTheme } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs'
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'
import { useColorScheme } from 'react-native'
import FontAwesome5 from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5'

// Screens
import Home from './screens/Home'
import Statistics from './screens/Statistics'
import Scanner from './screens/Scanner'
import Activity from './screens/Activity'
import Personal from './screens/Personal'
import DailySummaryFood from './screens/DailySummaryFood'
import AfterScan from './screens/AfterScan'

//Screen names
const homeName = 'Home'
const statisticName = 'Statistics'
const scannerName = 'Scanner'
const activityName = 'Activity'
const personalName = 'Personal'
const dailysummaryfood = 'DailySummaryFood'
const afterscan = 'AfterScan'

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator()

const MyTheme = {
  dark: false,
  colors: {
    primary: '',
    background: '#0F1E40',
    card: '',
    text: 'white',
    border: 'white',
    notification: '',
  },
}

const MyThemeDark = {
  dark: true,
  colors: {
    primary: '',
    background: '#0F1E40',
    card: '',
    text: 'white',
    border: 'white',
    notification: '',
  },
}

function MainContainer() {
  const scheme = useColorScheme()
  return (
    <NavigationContainer theme={scheme === 'dark' ? MyThemeDark : MyTheme}>
      <Tab.Navigator
        initialRouteName={homeName}
        screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
            let iconName
            let rn = route.name
            if (rn === homeName) {
              iconName = focused ? 'home' : 'home'
            } else if (rn === statisticName) {
              iconName = focused ? 'chart-line' : 'chart-line'
            } else if (rn === scannerName) {
              iconName = focused ? 'qrcode' : 'qrcode'
            } else if (rn === activityName) {
              iconName = focused ? 'dumbbell' : 'dumbbell'
            } else if (rn === personalName) {
              iconName = focused ? 'user-alt' : 'user-alt'
            }
            return <FontAwesome5 name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />
          },
          headerShown: false,
        })}
        tabBarOptions={{
          activeTintColor: '#D25050',
          inactiveTintColor: '#212121',
          style: { paddingBottom: 100, height: 700 },
          labelStyle: { paddingBottom: 10, fontSize: 0.1 },
          tabStyle: { backgroundColor: 'white', height: 80 },
        }}
      >
        <Tab.Screen name={homeName} component={Home} />
        <Tab.Screen name={statisticName} component={Statistics} />
        <Tab.Screen name={scannerName} component={Scanner} />
        <Tab.Screen name={activityName} component={Activity} />
        <Tab.Screen name={personalName} component={Personal} />
        <Tab.Screen name={dailysummaryfood} component={DailySummaryFood} />
        <Tab.Screen name={afterscan} component={AfterScan} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}

export default MainContainer
```

Tried declaring another Tab Navigator as well as another NavigationContainer but this is not possible since there is only 1 allowed.

I also tried a while loop running through the code 5 times, didn't work aswell.

Comment: Are you finding something like this? [https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators)

Comment: Tabs have limited screen real estate. I would recommend using a `more...` tab that launches a separate stack navigator with the additional screens.